# Error in redirecting my spring application to different domain on mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I am working on a Spring application which runs on mobile and web. On web everything runs fine but on mobile when the form is posted, its hits the controller and the controller is redirecting to other application.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/common", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLandingPage(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
logger.debug("Received request to set partner info");
Device currentDevice                = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(req);
setCookies(response);
Properties props = new Properties();
try {
    props.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "sampleApp.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.fatal(new StringBuilder("MainController : setCookies() : Error while reading sampleApp.properties "+e));
}catch (Exception e) {
    logger.fatal(new StringBuilder("MainController : setCookies() : Error while reading sampleApp.properties "+e));
}
if(currentDevice.isMobile() || currentDevice.isTablet()){
    return "redirect:"+props.getProperty("popcorn-mobile-url");
} else {               
    return "redirect:"+props.getProperty("popcorn-web-url");
}
}
```

When the control goes to the redirect location I get "error loading page" on the screen.

In JSP I am using following jQuery libraries.

```
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/mobile/mobile-config.js"></script> 
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/mobile/plugins.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I woul duse a deviceinterceptor, somethign like below :

```
public class DeviceInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {    
private final DeviceResolver deviceResolver;

    private Device device;

    /**
     * Create a device resolving {@link HandlerInterceptor} that defaults to a
     * {@link LiteDeviceResolver} implementation.
     */
    public DeviceInterceptor() {
        this(new LiteDeviceResolver());
    }

    public DeviceInterceptor(DeviceResolver deviceResolver) {
        this.deviceResolver = deviceResolver;
    }

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws Exception    {
        device = deviceResolver.resolveDevice(request);
        request.setAttribute(DeviceUtils.CURRENT_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE, device);
        return true;
    }

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    if (device.isMobile()) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("/mobile/" + modelAndView.getViewName());
        }else {
            modelAndView.setViewName("/jsp/" + modelAndView.getViewName());
        }           
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering .. even i am doing the same.. in case of mobile i am calling the page which are tailored for mobile device only.. but i am getting the problem because the location to which i am redirecting, is in different domain.. so i am getting the "error loading page" fro jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js.

Comment: the interceptor means you have a single poin of responsibility, rather than defining it in each controller. What exact message are you getting ? If the page is not there, well it won't work.